# How to apply style only for mobile device?

Tags: javascript, css, media-queries

I'am creating new web site. My intention is creating one page for desktop and mobile and set styles depend of device (mobile or desktop). I know I can achieve everything with pure javascript, but I would like to use also CSS and media queries. My question is: how can I set style only for mobile devices using CSS media queries? I was trying to use:

```
@media only screen{
     style...
}
```

But it works for both, mobile and dekstop browsers.

Comment: There is no hard distinction between a "mobile device" and a "desktop".  Something like a tablet with a docking station and an external monitor can be either or both at the same time.  Instead, you should identify characteristics of the device such as screen size that you want to target specific formatting for and then use [`@media` directives](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) to target those specific screen sizes.

Comment: No exact way to target only mobile devices but as others have stated you can rely on screen width. One thing to keep in mind, is that the media type `screen` is intended for color computer screens, and `handheld` is intended for handheld devices. Though this won't work alone to target mobile devices; you would still need to include rules. [More information on Media Types](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/media.html).

Answer (score 5):

You can not simply target mobile but have to give **break point** in order for it to work. You will have to use **min-width** or **max-width** for that to work

```
/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-width : 321px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen and (max-width : 320px) {
/* Styles */
}
```

**Example:** This will hide div with class of sidebar and set container width to 100% on smaller screens

```
 @media only screen and (max-width : 321px) {
        .sidebar {
                display:none;
         }

         .container{
             width:100%;
           }

    }
```

Comment: I know, I was trying that also, but that still works for both, desktop and mobiles.

Comment: So what you want to display on desktop screen

Comment: When page is displaying on mobile browsers, I need to hide left side of page(including menu) and set 100% width for the right site content. With Javascript i can achieve that, i was wondering, can I do that with media queries.

Comment: @Shagohad yes you can just insert you css code within this media query and it should do the trick

Comment: thanks for update, but this still no resolving my problem, beacause there is a lot of smartphones with Full HD screen resolution and above.

Answer (score 1):

If the styling, and even content, is entirely different from mobile to desktop, using a framework like Bootstrap makes this really easy. You can follow their strategy by creating hidden-xs and visible-xs classes with your own media queries, and apply those classes to different divs. Not the DRYest way of doing it, but gets the job done.

```css
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 375px) 
  and (max-device-width: 667px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
  and (orientation: portrait) { 
  
    .hidden-xs {
      display: none;
     }
    
    .visible-xs {
      display: block;
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting your styles based on screen-size rather than device?

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

Comment: Yea, I was trying with that.